# syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer change locale texts

Tags: flutter, syncfusion

I use `syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer` to display `pdf` files.
Now i want to change texts in page navigation popup and other default texts.

I got the following solution from ChatGPT and Didn't succeed :

```
import 'package:syncfusion_localizations/syncfusion_localizations.dart';
```

```
localizationsDelegates: [
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        SfGlobalLocalizations.delegate
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        const Locale('en'),
        const Locale('fa'),
      ],
```

`create intl_messages.arb`  file in `lib/110n` with the following code:

```
{
  "@@locale": "fa",
  "textviewer_paginationDialogCancelButton": "لغو",
  "textviewer_paginationDialogGoToPageButton": "برو به صفحه",
  "textviewer_paginationDialogPageCountLabel": "{pageCount}",
  "textviewer_paginationDialogPageNumberLabel": "شماره صفحه",
  "textviewer_searchBarClearButtonTooltip": "پاک کردن",
  "textviewer_searchBarHint": "جستجو",
  "textviewer_searchBarNextButtonTooltip": "بعدی",
  "textviewer_searchBarPreviousButtonTooltip": "قبلی",
  "textviewer_searchBarResultsCountLabel": "{currentResultCount}/{totalResultCount}"
}
```

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.